# Merging Errors Occurring datasets in R

Tags: r, merge, gis, data-mapping

I am trying to combine a few datasets. census and childrenfamily are easy. Same number of rows, come from the same source. However, I would like to place the variables I have from those mergeddata onto a map. In order to do this, I am under the impression that 1)I'm way in over my head and 2)I will need for the neighborhoods in my shapefile to correspond with the census and childrenfamily ones and 3)that it's 100% possible to do. Here is what I've got going on. Please please help me. I'm lost.

CENSUS AND CHILDRENFAMILY DATA MAGICKING

```
 census<-read.csv(file="Census_Demographics_2010.csv") 
 childrenfamily<-read.csv(file="ChildrenFamilyHealthWellBeing2010")
     mergedData=merge(census,childrenfamily,by.x="CSA2010",by.y="CSA2010",all=TRUE)
 newData<-as.matrix(mergedData)
 edu<-read.csv(file="Education_and_Youth_2010.csv")
 MergedData=merge(mergedData,edu,by.x="CSA2010",by.y="CSA2010",all=TRUE)
 newData<-cSplit(MergedData,sep="/","CSA2010","long",type.convert=TRUE)
 NewData<-cSplit(newData,sep="-","CSA2010","long",type.convert=TRUE)
 nhood<-read.csv("nhood_2010.csv")
 nbhd<-as.matrix(nhood)
 nbhd<-cSplit(nhood,sep="/","NBRDESC","long",type.convert=TRUE)
 nbhds<-cSplit(nbhd,sep="-","NBRDESC","long",type.convert=TRUE)
 nhoods<-nbhds[order(nbhds$NBRDESC),]
 class(nhoods$NBRDESC)
 [1] "factor"
 class(newDATA$CSA2010)
 [1] "character"
 nhoods2$NBRDESC<-as.character(nhoods2$NBRDESC)
 class(nhoods2$NBRDESC)
 [1] "character"
```

MAP MAGICKING

```
 library(rgdal)
 library(maptools)
 bmorehoods<-readOGR(dsn="/ladeedah/2010_Census_Neighborhoods",layer="2010_Census_Profile_by_Neighborhood_Statistical_Areas")
 library(ggplot2)
 data.points<- fortify(model=bmorehoods)
 bmore<-ggplot(data.points) + geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group=group))
```

So, I basically have neighborhood data that doesn't match up with GIS neighborhood data, and I'm wondering

1) Is there any better way to be doing this? 
2) Why, when I try to merge my data does R partake in these kind of shananigans:

```
 mapdata<-merge(nhoods2,NewDATA,by.x="NBRDESC",by.y="CSA2010",all=TRUE)
 Error in merge(nhoods2, NewDATA, by.x = "NBRDESC", by.y = "CSA2010", all = TRUE) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'merge': Error: object 'NewDATA' not found
```

> 

Comment: For your last issue it's a typo, NewDATA instead of NewData

Comment: oh actually, I did include another dataset that is a modification of NewData- it's got stuff like SOUTH HILTON rather than S. Hilton so that both files have the same names for neighborhoods.

Comment: regardless, it doesn't exist in your environment when you call merge.

Comment: yes it does after I do this stuff: newDATA[69,1]<-"MOUNT WASHINGTON"
> newDATA[70,1]<-"MOUNT WINANS"

Comment: Your variable naming is a bit of a nightmare to be honest. I would never have multiple variables which only differ in capitalisation. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html for one example of how to name variables consistently. In any case, the code in your comment isn't in the question, and not are the definition of `nhoods2` or `newDATA`.